# Remount reactjs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have two components on my react application that get data from an API.
One receives an image and the other, text.

I have a button on the bottom of my page, I wanted to use that to refresh those two components.

It should behave like refresh the whole page, But I believe this is not the best way since I am working with components.

I have found a few solutions saying to update the key but that doesn't fit my problem.
I have first to rebuild my component so it will do the HTTP requests from the external api`s.

I will use one of the components as example since they are quite similar:

```
componentDidMount() {

axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
  .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    this.setState({wiseDog:res.data.message})
    this.setState({isLoading:false})
})
  .catch( err => {
    this.setState({error:err.data.message})
  })
```

}

When the component is mounted, I render wiseDog state (this is my image link) on the html and it works.
From my footer component, I want to click a button and this will do a new request updating the image.

```
 <Fragment>
  <CssBaseline />
  <AppBar position="fixed" color="primary" className={classes.appBar}>
    <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
      <Fab color="secondary" aria-label="Add" className={classes.fabButton}>
        <Refresh />
      </Fab>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
</Fragment>
```

The button is the `<Refresh/>`

Does anyone knows what I could search or try to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put the code for the API call to a function and call it when `componentDidMount` and `onClick` of that FAB.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

componentDidMount(){
    this.requestUpdate();
}

requestUpdate = () => {
    // Make API call here and 'setState' when it completes
};

render(){
    return (
         <Fragment>
             <CssBaseline />
             <AppBar>
                 <Toolbar>
                     <Fab onClick={this.requestUpdate}>
                         <Refresh />
                    </Fab>
                 </Toolbar>
             </AppBar>
         </Fragment>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: can I use that as a helper method and export that function to use on my component and on the component where my refresh button is?

Comment: @Fix3r Yes, however you'd need to pass `setState` to that function too.

Answer (score 0):

Your refresh component will hit the same API and save the response in local state and pass that state as prop to the other child component through parent component and render the image and text again.

Comment: So, If I understood you, It is better to have a helper method to do the API call, so I can reuse it within my refresh button as well? That helper method would, for example, send the new state to my component... is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: Yes , u have to do that .Because you cannot set state of child component from other child component , so you have to pass the value to your component.